# Styling export XLS using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, excel

How do i make the columns wider and the headers different other than the column name of the table in mysql? and how do i make it have a larger font? I am new to exporting excel files i have no idea how to do it, i've tried researching about it but i didn't understand it either. thank you in advance for your help.

Here is my export.php

```
<?php


require 'config.php';
$SQL = "SELECT prod_brand, prod_name, prod_category, prod_price, prod_desc, prod_quantity from inventory";
$header = '';
$result ='';
$exportData = mysql_query ($SQL ) or die ( "Sql error : " . mysql_error( ) );

$fields = mysql_num_fields ( $exportData );

for ( $i = 0; $i < $fields; $i++ )
{
    $header .= mysql_field_name( $exportData , $i ) . "\t";
}

while( $row = mysql_fetch_row( $exportData ) )
{
    $line = '';
    foreach( $row as $value )
    {                                            
        if ( ( !isset( $value ) ) || ( $value == "" ) )
        {
            $value = "\t";
        }
        else
        {
            $value = str_replace( '"' , '""' , $value );
            $value = '"' . $value . '"' . "\t";
        }
        $line .= $value;
    }
    $result .= trim( $line ) . "\n";
}
$result = str_replace( "\r" , "" , $result );

if ( $result == "" )
{
    $result = "\nNo Record(s) Found!\n";                        
}

header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=InventoryExport'.date('m-d-Y H:i:s').'.xls');
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
print "$header\n$result";

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

See the PHP code sample from this link, where the headers names are custom and the rows are extracted from a database:
http://www.easyxls.com/manual/basics/export-list-to-excel.html

To increase the font size of the header use this code:

```
     // Create an instance of the object used to format the cells
     $xlsAutoFormat = new COM("EasyXLS.ExcelAutoFormat");

     //Set the style of the header
     $xlsHeaderStyle = new COM("EasyXLS.ExcelStyle");
     $xlsHeaderStyle->setFontSize(18);
     $xlsAutoFormat->setHeaderRowStyle($xlsHeaderStyle);
```